# GVIM tries to open files of same type as current scheme

Tags: gvim

If I am editing a file in GVIM and for agurgument sakes the file is a XML file with the extension ".xml", and I click "File > Open" ... GVIM will filter by files of type ".xml" which is fairly annoying.

It is annoying because often I have files which do not have the appropriate extension for the type of content they contain, which means that when I want to open another file I have to change the filtering every time.

So either getting rid of this filtering or adding extensions for a file type would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this question is still actual, but if it is here are some recommendations.

1. Vim/gVim and the likes, are keyboard oriented editors. Although it is possible to open file via File/Open menus, the preferable way is doing so via `:e` command.
2. If you are opening them via File/... you can always enter `*.*` (by keyboard) upon which gVim will show all files (regardless of extension).
3. If you're opening them via `:e`, options

   *set wildmenu

   set wildignore=*.exe,*.obj,*.rsp*

can be useful. The other one tells vim to ignore given extensions.

4. If you wish to assign a filetype to an extension to which it wouldn't usually be given, you can do that upon opening file via autocmd command.

If I've completely misunderstood the question, yell in the comments.

Comment: Marked as the answer based on point #2. I have not had the chance to try it yet, but will when back at work. Thanks for the feedback :-)